# Is there a nuked FireFox 35 installation?

Tags: windows-7, firefox

I just upgraded my FF to the latest version - 35, or 35.1. All my tabs were gone, the space above the tabs is wastefully **huuuge** and I can't get to options (the green marked buttons work but the red marked ones - they "click" but don't open anything).

The biggest issue - when I type in e.g. *google.com* on the URL line, nothing happens.

I've restarted the computer a few times and of course reinstalled the Foxy. I checked different proxy settings. Still, the same misbehavior. I'm on Win 7, just as previously, nothing else has changed. Both IE and Cr work as previously, i.e. well.

What is that and how can I remedy it?![image]

Comment: It doesn't help you directly, but I thought that it might be worth mentioning that I'm on 35.0.1 and haven't had any of these issues, so it's probably not a general problem with that version.

Comment: Try safe mode https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-firefox-issues-using-safe-mode

Comment: You said you reinstalled Firefox, so I assume you don't care about bookmarks/history/settings. If so, try deleting any "Mozilla" folder in the %appdata%" directory and see if that helps.

Comment: @MattChampion Well, it doesn't **resolve** the issue but it definitely carries me **forward**. I understood that it's my machine only, of course, but now it's officially confirmed.

Comment: @AndréDaniel I do care about history and such but I care even more about being able to use the browser, hehe. I'll try that immediately.

Comment: @Zonder The first hint there says to click the button on the far right (three lines icon). That's one of the buttons that didn't do anything - nothing happened). But clearing the *AppData* stuff seems to do the trick.

Comment: @AndréDaniel It worked. Mucho thanko, matie! Post that as a reply, please. And add two things. #1 The three possible locations of the *AppData* directory. #2 Tell people to **make a copy** of the *Mozilla* directory. I was stupid enough to remove it. Now I can't tell where I've been.   :)

Comment: @KonradViltersten the second option was best to try then "holding shift down while clicking firefox" look like you sorted now though (I was going to suggest that also depending if safe more worked)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the `Firefox` directory in the `%AppData%\Mozilla` one (which expands to `<your user folder>\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla`), that will reset all Firefox settings and add-ons.

On Mac, the folder is either `~/Library/Application Support/Firefox` or `~/Library/Mozilla/Firefox`.

On Linux, the folder is `~/.mozilla/firefox`.

See this [MozillaZine wiki article](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder_-_Firefox) about the profile folder for more info.

Make sure to backup that folder somewhere first if you care about your browsing history, bookmarks, etc.

Comment: Actually, this exposes a bigger problem. I've tried to switch to Chrome once or twice **but** I always get stuck on the usability issue of Chrome. There are plugins to FF that I can't find on Chrome making FF the only possible choice. That's vulnerability. Please see [this here](http://superuser.com/questions/871612/where-to-find-coversion-list-of-plugins-between-ff-and-cr) on the subject.

Comment: @KonradViltersten using Chrome is a really bad idea as it's proprietary software coming from a company whose business model is selling personal data/analytics/advertising... Not the kind of company I would trust. Chrome is also bloated with all these account features, online cloud/sync with your google account/etc... Firefox is way better in terms of privacy.